# Как сохранять галочки при перезагрузке страницы?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Как сделать, что бы при перезагрузке страницы галочки оставались так как их выбрал пользователь. Это нужно записывать в бд и потом считывать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".glyphicon").click(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass("glyphicon-question-sign")) {
                $(this).removeClass("glyphicon-question-sign").removeClass("blue2");
                $(this).addClass("glyphicon-ok-sign").addClass("green2");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("glyphicon-ok-sign").removeClass("green2");
                $(this).addClass("glyphicon-question-sign").addClass("blue2");
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.jumbotron {
 background-image: url(http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/716/cache/canvasback-ducks-maryland_71644_990x742.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat
}
.jumbotron h1 {
 font-weight: bold;
}
.bigger {
 margin-top: -4px;
 font-size: 150%;
}
.blue2 {
 color: #8C84BF;
}
.green2 {
 color: #02A10F;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Задача 1<span class="pull-right bigger blue2 glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Задача 2<span class="pull-right bigger blue2 glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Задача 3<span class="pull-right bigger blue2 glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Задача 4<span class="pull-right bigger blue2 glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> </li>
        </div>
```

Comment: Храните галочки в <s>сберкассе</s>localstorage https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage

Comment: Если нужно запоминать надолго, то лучше в БД. Если на время, то тут два вариант. Если эти галочки индивидуальны для каждого запроса, то можно в куках. Если нет, можно в сессии.

Comment: Вот статейка, как - раз пример с галочками. http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_cookie

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая штука как local storage, она позволяет хранить данные в браузере до очистки кеша и куки. Ознакомиться можно здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage